# Find recent deployment date time (History) in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There is issue in one of our application. Unfortunately, It wasn't configured on continuous integration. Now we need to find out the recent / latest deployment history with date time.

Could you please help me to find the deployment history in App Service?

Comment: How were you deploying the app without continuous integration? FTP or syncing a cloud drive?

Comment: We are deploying using Visual Studio by publish option.

Comment: Did you use Visual Studio to do a FTP or Web Deploy publish? Probably the lather? First thing that pops up is have a look at the created datetime of the assembly of your application, that should at least tell you when it was _built_.

Comment: We are using Web Deploy. Yes i agree with you, Assembly datetime is not matching with version controlling check-in datetime.

Answer (score 9):

You can go to the App Service, click 'Activity log' and set the timespan in which you think the deployment might have occured (with a maximum of 90 days in the past).

It shows you when the web application was updated. I just checked, it looks something like this:

[image: App Service Activity Log displaying 'Update website' entry]

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I agree with you, we could see the log in azure "App Service". But, this history doesn't match with assembly build date-time. How this could be happened? Do you have any idea?

Comment: That depends on how much difference there is between the two: is it local vs. UTC Time? Or maybe you deployed an already built assembly? If you don't make changes and the assembly was already built, it might deploy the 'old' version.

Answer (score 6):

> Could you please help me to find the deployment history in App Service?

You could check it by review the MSDeploy log. Here is the folder path in Azure Web App.

```
D:\home\LogFiles\SiteExtensions\MSDeploy
```

There is a appManagerLog.xml file in this log folder. We can view it from kudu. Here is a sample log file. It will add 2 entries to this log if a deploy action executed. We could get the latest deploy date from the last entry of this log file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry type="Message" time="2017-06-16T06:35:17.9453425Z">
        <message>[Verbose] Skip function trigger and logicapp sync because function is not enabled.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry type="Message" time="2017-06-16T06:35:17.9453425Z">
        <message>[Verbose] AutoSwap is not enabled</message>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

Answer (score 3):

Kudu API now shows a log for previous deployments in Json.

1. Access Kudu for your app service: https://[app_service_name].scm.azurewebsites.net
2. Click Deployments from Rest API section. Direct link: https://[app_service_name]/api/deployments

It shows the list of previous deployments with most recent at the top. When you do have CI/CD set up correctly, it will shows commit hash, build and release IDs, so you can trace the deployment back to the pipeline entry/commit.

Comment: the result is empty if you deploy by WebDeploy. at least in my case