# How to check / log deployment history for azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In in azure app service, how could we log a complete record (like user/alias) when a code is deployed or published to app service from visual studio ? Can it be monitored using application insights ?

I had overcome few similar questions here like [Find recent deployment date time (History) in Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566795/find-recent-deployment-date-time-history-in-azure-app-service) but it does not display information alias / user deployed code. Also CI/CD is not enabled.